# Adding second condition in LINQ JOIN,

Tags: c#, linq

I have looked around and found a few posts on adding a second condition to a JOIN clause but they are always instances of having one column link to another but in my instance I need to just have a column equal a certain value. The RAW SQL I am trying to imitate is:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TimeCardHeader AS tch2 on tch1.EmployeeID = tch2.EmployeeID && tch2.WeekEndingDate = @PayPeriod
```

As you can see my second join condition is to match a column value from the table to a variable. I have tried the following LINQ queires but they all fail.

```
join leftth2 in db.TimeCardHeaders on th1.EmployeeID equals leftth2.EmployeeID AND leftth2.WeekEndingDate == PayPeriod into leftjointh2

join leftth2 in db.TimeCardHeaders on th1.EmployeeID equals leftth2.EmployeeID && leftth2.WeekEndingDate == PayPeriod into leftjointh2

join leftth2 in db.TimeCardHeaders on new
{
    employeeID = th1.EmployeeID,
    weekEndingDate = leftth2.WeekEndingDate
} equals new
{
    employeeID = leftth2.EmployeeID,
    weekEndingDate = PayPeriod
}
```

The first two fail  saying `AND` and `&&` are not valid, the last fails saying `leftth2` is not in the scope of the left side.

What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition

```
tch2.WeekEndingDate = @PayPeriod
```

doesn't feel like part of the join to me - it's not comparing data in two different rows. It feels like it should be part of what you're joining *on*, leading to:

```
join leftth2 in db.TimeCardHeaders.Where(p => p.WeekEndingDate == PayPeriod)
    on th1.EmployeeID equals leftth2.EmployeeID into leftjointh2
```

Comment: Your right, in the SQL it is placed in the JOIN clause but it is more of a WHERE clause. I have updated my LINQ add the WHERE following your example and it is working. I will mark as answer when the required time has passed. Thank you.